# how to dynamically retrieve data from rest API and store it in workitem fields as dropdown picklist in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops

how to dynamically retrieve data from rest API and store it in workitem fields as dropdown picklist in azure devops

tried writing javascript and powershell script to retrieve but they are not working as expected

Comment: What data do you want to retrieve? Where is the data from, inside or outside of your Azure DevOps organization?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider developing an Azure DevOps extension to [extend the work item form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-workitem-extension?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops). This can let you add some custom forms on the web UI of work items to display certain data you want.

1. If the data is from within your current Azure DevOps organization, you can [call the related REST API in the extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/call-rest-api?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops) to get the data.
2. If the data is from outside of your current organization or from the 3rd-party platforms, you need to check if the outside platforms has provided available Azure DevOps extensions that can let you retrieve data from the outside platforms into the work items of Azure DevOps. If no available extensions, you might also need to develop the extension by yourself.

---